# Passing Comma Separated List to Function with VARIDIAC parameter as input

Tags: sql, teiid

I have a user defined function that takes a VARIADIC parameter as an input:

```
func(name string, VARIADIC values double) returns Blob

Example: select func('abc', 35.2,35.3,35.5)
```

How can I pass row based float/double values to comma separated double type in TEIID

```
From:
35.2
35.3
35.5

To:
35.2,35.3,35.5

as a single double/float comma separated variable.
```

Thank you

Comment: That isn't java code. Please remove the java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the ARRAY_AGG aggregate function:

```
select func('abc', select array_agg(double_col) from something)
```

There's also array constructors ARRAY[value,...] and (value, ...)